# Cant install the selenium IDE & Firebug on firefox 55.0.3

Tags: selenium

I wanna install  selenium IDE & Firebug on firefox 55.0.3 but i cant install on it.

I tried to install on it but i cant

Plz help

Comment: What is the issue you are facing

Comment: I cant able to install.Its sow the gray button when install through it                                             https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

Comment: try with previous version of firefox

Answer (score 1):

It was a bad news for the tester community since Selenium IDE no long works from Firefox 55 onwards. Now you have 2 choices:

1- Try with [previous version](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox) of firefox (Temporary solution)

2- Use [Selenium IDE alternatives](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/selenium-ide-alternative-firefox-chrome/) (Highly Recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is not compatible with Firefox 55. Try using an older version of Firefox.

Refer the below link:

[Selenium IDE not compatible with Firefox 55](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4406)

Answer (score 0):

There is Firefox 52.3.0 ESR version Portable right here: https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox-portable-esr

If you use it, you have got 2 advantages:

1. Selenium IDE will work fine
2. You can reproduce bugs, if any was finded for last version of Firefox for Windows XP and Vista